# Link is not shown only if it has a specific class

Tags: html, css

Here is the full code:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVPUZUO2Z6YQ

For some reason, my link is ***hidden*** **only** when I'm using `sponsor-link` class. Every other class is okay, even if other classes are identical, like `button-link` class:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.button-link {
}
.sponsor-link {
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="aaaa" class="sponsor-link">
        11111
  </a>
</body>
</html>
```

How is it making any sense? What is the actual problem with the class name `sponsor-link`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to Ad Block being enabled. Pause it on the page you're working on and then you'll see that `sponsor-link` style will work. But of course, your best bet is to change the name of that style.